# Configure my vps and domain name

Tags: webserver

I have a vps set with an padres and i also have a domain name at a hosting provider. I want to connect the domain name to the padres of the vps

my hosting provider doesn't give support how to fix that. Can anyone help me? maybe a manual

thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by Padres?? Do you mean IP address?? Your registrar should be helping you out with this. If you need help, we have answered that question here before if you want to do a search. Otherwise say so and I will poke around for an answer- it may be somewhat generic, but it may be helpful.

Comment: thank you, but i don't know what i should search for. And yes, I mean ip-adres. can you help me out please? my hosting provider is not giving any support.

Comment: Here are two I found quickly: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67546/domain-name-not-resolving-with-webhost-nameservers-and-without-www/67547#67547 and 
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67125/how-do-i-update-my-dns-server-so-that-it-points-to-my-new-web-server/67128#67128 See if these help. I can do a wider search if you have questions. Please ignore the title and focus on the answers.

Comment: thanks you, Do i need to install a dns server on the vas? i followed all the steps, but it still doesn't work. The vps and the domain name are two different products at the same hosting provider

Comment: You do not want to install a DNS. You always want to use the registrars DNS primarily because that is what is likely already set up for your domain name. Your registrar will have a website that you log into and use their control panel to set your DNS records. Once set, it can take anywhere from 1-48 hours to propagate the records throughout the Internet. Often people get confused because they can see several DNS options- the registrar, the host, and on the server, etc. They often use the wrong one. It is your registrars DNS that will work.

Comment: I've done everything from the instructions and it's still not working. Do i need to do anything with my vps? Maybe installing something?

Comment: What is your domain name?? I will be in and out quite often today- but I will look into it and see what can be done.

Comment: I checked out a few things and all looks okay, though there may be other setting to help you with later. For now, you have to deal with your registrar. When I enter ellikos.com into my browser, I see: *The registrant details for ellikos.com have not been validated yet, if you are the registrant please check your e-mail for instructions on how to validate and activate your domain.* **This is critical.** Check your e-mail. If you do not have an e-mail from your registrar asking for confirmation, then you will want to contact them directly and try again. Nothing will work until this is fixed.

Comment: Thank You....Its working now. But how do i get rid of the ipadres of the vps? I just want domain name to remain in the adress bar. Is this possible?

Comment: That maybe something that your host has set-up. This is not normal behavior and can be fixed. It has to do with the configuration or the htaccess file. If you can open a new question, it would much easier to work through it to find you an answer.